# Is there a Sublime Text plugin that favours frequently opened files when using 'Goto Anything'?

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text

90% of my 'Goto Anything' usage is opening the same 10 or so files. It would be ideal if this was factored into the search results, to reduce the amount of keystrokes required. Is there a plugin that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a mruf (most recent used file) plugin.

I'm using this one:

https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/RecentActiveFiles

Enjoy!

Comment: I installed this in Sublime 3. It mentions `super+k + super+t` keys. This is the Windows key right? It does nothing for me when I activate one of these keys.

Comment: Never mind, I remapped the `recent_active_files` command to `ctrl+o` and now it works. This is a great plugin.